# Model a Rubix Cube in an Array Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, rubiks-cube

Does anybody have any idea on how to model a rubix cube in an array? I can't seem to think of a way?

Comment: A better way is to use JSON to model a rubik's cube instead of array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code for this one is available:

```
 http://software.rubikscube.info/AnimCube/
```

Your in luck, it's Java. :)

This paper shows different ways to model the cube -

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=801107&coll=portal&dl=ACM

and another exploratory paper...

http://www.chilton.com/~jimw/rubik.html

but a simple answer would be a 3x3x3 array with 3 digits.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try a 1 dimensional array. But you could have a 3 dimensional array.

And array of 3x3 arrays of each side.